# Setting a remote authentication server on a router

Tags: authentication, router

I'm looking for a way to set an external authentication server that will work on many/most wireless routers. Or , alternatively several ways that will work on different wireless routers. It needs to be done programmatically, meaning, that a computer connected to the router needs to be able to use some api maybe to do this.
I don't know if this is possible, I tried to find answers on Google, but with limited knowledge, I'm not sure that I'm even looking in the right place.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I'm trying to create an application that will allow people to open there WIFI so other people can borrow it.

The ide is:

To borrowed wifis:
Create an account with *the application*.
Log into *the application*. This app will, when you are logged in, automatically connect you to a wifi nearby that is shared. The share wifi will only be accessible if you have a valid username-password combo with *the application*

To share your wifi:
From the same application, you go into some menu and press "share this wifi", and somehow, I need this to configure the currently connected router to use the an external authentication server as well as the current WIFI key. So that, people can essentially use their *the application* username-password combo to log into this router.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: good luck. AFIAK there is no standard between all the different router manufacturers. so you might have to write your own.  You could make look at TR-69, that *might* work.  but that will only cover a small subset..

Comment: Any small subset is okay. I figure that to support as many routers as possible, I need to find a solution for one subset at the time, with a fallback that guides the user to do it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try google-ing for **Radius Server** , **WPA(2) Enterprise** , or **802.1x**.
These keywords are very related.

To setup a radius authentication you need to have a router which supports wpa(2) enterprise and a radius server (probably google-able how to setup on windows/linux).

Programmatically connecting is possible, only a bit more difficult because it uses wpa(2) enterprise authentication.

If you could supply some more details i should be able to help you further.

Comment: I have added some more info in the question regarding what exactly I'm trying to achieve. Please tell if I'm still being to vague/confusing.

Comment: The details are OK.
But i dont know if this is even possible, setting up *any* router to use this seems a bit impossible while just setting up your own router may be easy.
Routers dont have a standard or api that you can use, the user has to do it manually, you could try to guide him though.
Also, this cant be done without requiring every user of the network to reauthenticate.


What is possible is that the share computer creates a second wireless network with the next free wifi adapter (requires at least 1 unused wlan card).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. Everything is possible, the impossible just takes a little longer.

Comment: That's the spirit! Good luck!

Comment: @sigsve you could also take a look at UPnP but afaik that only allows for port-forwarding control